# The sdk platform-tools version (24.0.4rc1) is too old to check APIs compiled with 25

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

I am receiving following warning: "The sdk platform-tools version (24.0.4rc1) is too old to check APIs compiled with 25". But I updated my SDKs and tools. What might be the cause? I read and tried answers to similar problems but none of them did work.

My gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.***"
         minSdkVersion 19
         targetSdkVersion 25
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
  }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REhJg.png)

[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOrrH.png)

Comment: I think this is because the SDK you have in your machine is of version 24. Try to check that out and if its true, download version 25 and everything will be fine :)

Comment: My sdk version is 25

Comment: Try to refresh your project and see what happens. Go to File -> Invalidate cache/Restart

Comment: I tried several times, it didn't work

Comment: Did you try rebuilding your whole project?

Comment: Yes, I tried to rebuild whole project